# Time Difference in minutes on 2 'Time' Data type

Tags: custom-field, time

I have 2-time fields (Start time and End Time). I need to calculate the difference in minutes. I have tried with below code, but does not work.

```
 Double var = Math.Floor((Double.valueOf(mem.End__c.getTime()) - Double.valueOf(mem.Start__c.getTime())) / (1000.0*60.0*60.0));
```

The trigger is not getting saved, saying that getTime() method is not valid. I guess it work for Datetime field.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `Time` class in apex [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm#apex_methods_system_time)

You can use `hour()` to get the hour and convert it to minutes for both time fields and compute the difference.

You can also look at other functions `minute() and second()` as well in the link provided to get more accurate results.